# Uniform buffer interface block: mat2 vs two vec2s?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I have a simple 2D renderer in Vulkan. I used to have the following interface block.

```c
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform CameraParams {
    vec2 u_camTranslation;
    mat2 u_camRotScale;
};
```

But then I noticed that (I suspect due to padding) it's 32 bytes wide.

If I replace the `mat2` by two `vec2`s, the size goes down to 24 bytes.

```c
layout(set = 0, binding = 0) uniform CameraParams {
    vec2 u_camTranslation;
    vec2 u_camRotScale_X;
    vec2 u_camRotScale_Y;
};
```

My question has two parts:

1. Why does the first code have padding?
2. Is there any disadvantage to the second code?

---

I have been reading the Vulkan spec (15.5.4) for the alignment rules, but I have trouble understanding why my first code has padding.

From the spec:

> Standard Buffer Layout
>
> 1. If the scalarBlockLayout feature is enabled on the device and the storage class is Uniform, StorageBuffer, PhysicalStorageBuffer, or
>    PushConstant then every member must be aligned according to its scalar
>    alignment.
>
> 2️⃣. All vectors must be aligned according to their scalar alignment.
>
> 3. If the uniformBufferStandardLayout feature is not enabled on the device, then any member of an OpTypeStruct with a storage class of
>    Uniform and a decoration of Block must be aligned according to its
>    extended alignment.
>
> 4️⃣. Every other member must be aligned according to its base alignment.
>
> Base Alignment
>
> - A matrix type inherits base alignment from the equivalent array declaration.
> - An array has a base alignment equal to the base alignment of its element type.
> - A two-component vector has a base alignment equal to twice its scalar alignment

So when I read this I think we should be applying the "base alignment". But for some reason it looks like maybe "extended alignment" is being used? Rule number 3 applies to structs only, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

When it says "any member of an OpTypeStruct with ...", the "with ..." applies to the *struct*, not the *members* of it. That is, if that feature is not enabled, if a struct is used in a uniform block, its members must have extended alignment.

> Is there any disadvantage to the second code?

Besides the obvious? No.